# How to write queries with concatenation and alias in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by, union

I have two tables A and B with following schema :-

Table A -> Two columns Principal (varchar) and LoginTime (Timestamp)

Table B -> Two columns Username (varchar) and LoginTime (Timestamp)

Now I have to run a query on both tables, union them and then order by username. So I wrote a query like this :-

```
select Principal AS Uname || ', ' ||
       LoginTime from A
       where LoginTime > 1430890465
UNION ALL
select Username AS Uname || ', ' ||
       LoginTime from B
       where LoginTime > 1430890465
order by Uname;
```

But the above does not seems to work and gives following error :-

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
>   00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Principal AS Uname || ', ' ||
>          LoginTime

It is syntactically incorrect. You can concatenate two columns. You cannot concatenate a column with another column's alias.

Since you are concatenating the `username` and `timestamp` columns, you just need to add an **alias** to the **concatenated columns**, i.e. the expression.

```
select (Principal || ', ' ||
       LoginTime) AS Uname from A
       where LoginTime > 1430890465
UNION ALL
select (Username || ', ' ||
       LoginTime) AS Uname from B
       where LoginTime > 1430890465
order by Uname;
```

I have added the braces to the expression, i.e. the concatenated columns to make it easy for you to understand that the **alias** `Uname` is for the **concatenated value**.

Comment: So I believe that the above will order considering (Principal/Username and LoginTime) combined as one string and then sorting it alphabetically. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. You would be sorting it as a string. i.e. you are sorting the concatenated value `Uname`.

Comment: Thanks Lalit for your answer. Selected your answer as the correct one because of simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

`as` goes after the column you want to give an alias to:

```
select Principal  || ', ' || LoginTime  AS Uname
from A
where LoginTime > 1430890465

union all

select Username || ', ' || LoginTime
from B
where LoginTime > 1430890465
```

Comment: In my case Username and Principal are same. So why do we need to put Uname after LoginTime?

Comment: @Siddharth: You don't have to put an alias, it's just if you want, then you should do it right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry if I am missing the concept, but I want an alias for Principal/ Username columns as Uname. For my DB Principal and Username have similar data. So do I still need to put Uname after LoginTime ?

Comment: @Siddharth: Yes, the way that I've shown you above.

Comment: @suslov Well, you don't need an outer query, the union all would work fine. The order by would be applied to the union set.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Yeah, checked processing phases. Thanks